# QUrl: incorrect link

Tags: c++, qt, http, request, qurl

I have a link on Steam market listings: 
`http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Gut%20Knife%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Battle-Scarred%29`

Now I'm trying to do a get request using `QNetworkAccessManager`:

```
auto manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
auto url = QUrl(link, QUrl::StrictMode);
auto request = QNetworkRequest(url);

manager->get(request);
```

But when I try to output my url, I get just this:

```
qDebug() << link << url;
"http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Gut%20Knife%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Battle-Scarred%29"
QUrl ("")
```

Using `TolerantMode` in QUrl I get just empty page after the query.
So, QUrl considers my link is incorrect. How should I do that query? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(link.toUtf8());
qDebug() << url;
```

The output is:

```
QUrl( "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/★ Gut Knife | Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)" )
```